# Gitlab API job_token_scope returns 404

Tags: gitlab-api

I was trying to use [gitlab API request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_job_token_scopes.html#get-a-projects-cicd-job-token-access-settings).
My request:
`curl -s --url 'https://my.gitlab/api/v4/projects/'$project_id'/job_token_scope' --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: '$token''`
returns json with 404 not found. However request
`curl -s --url 'https://my.gitlab/api/v4/projects/'$project_id'' --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: '$token''`
works fine.

I'm using gitlab-ce 15.11.3.
The token's user is owner of this project